# ClassNotFoundException: "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"

Tags: jdbc

I have spent a few hours trying to track this one down. A lot of people have reported this error, but ultimately a solution was found. But, none of those solutions worked for me.

I'm developing a Java application using Eclipse. Here is a code snippet:

```
import java.sql.*

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
```

Eclipse spots an error immediately: `Unhandled exception type: ClassNotFoundException`.

Project properties indicate the build path includes JRE System Library (jre7).

In Eclipse, I can see that JRE7 includes sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.class

Answer (score 0):

[Class.forName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) declares that it throws ClassNotFoundException. And this is a checked exception. So you must catch it, or declare that your method throws it as well.

Learn about exception handling by reading the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). This is basic stuff that every Java developer must know.

Once you master exceptions, please learn about JDBC. The JDBC-ODBC driver is something that should not be used anymore, for years. Every database now has a native JDBC driver.

Comment: JB,Thanks for responding to my posting.

Comment: JB Thanks for respondong to my posting. I will follow-up on your suggestion about exceptions. My Java app will export results into Excel. I was not able to find a JDBC driver for Excel, thus my use of JDBC-ODBC. Do you know of a readily available native JDBC driver for Excel?

Comment: Excel is not a relational database. Why don't you use an Excel API (like POI or JExcel)?

Answer (score 0):

"Every database now has a native JDBC driver."

I wish this was true - however there are niche database systems that do not. At my work specifically we are stuck with a database system that is part of a larger piece of software that we need to run the business and cannot easily replace. There is no JDBC driver for it and the developers of the database system have clearly stated that creating one is not a goal of theirs.

You may have good reason to not like the JDBC-ODBC driver, but there are cases where it is the only option.